# Question on proving continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

My goal is to show that $(\vec{y})^{-1}$ is continuous, where $\vec{y}(x)= (x, \frac{1}{x})$ on the domain $x > 0$.

Now clearly $\vec{y}$ itself is continuous and it is bijective; I first thought to use the theorem that states if a function $f$ has a compact domain and is continuous then its inverse is also continuous. However, the domain $(0, \infty)$ clearly is not compact so no luck there.

There is also no luck using the inverse value theorem since the Jacobian matrix of $\vec{y}$ is singular.

Maybe I am overthinking this but I do not know what else I can do to achieve my goal. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are certainly overthinking.Consider a convergent sequence $\vec{y}(k_n) \to \vec{y}(k)$ (in the topology induced by $\mathbb R^2$) and prove that $k_n \to k$. It should be obvious : if a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$ is convergent in the usual topology then its components are convergent.

Comment: A VVF if continuous iff its components are continuous. Further, $\left(\vec{y}(x)\right)^{-1}=\vec{y}(1/x)$.

Comment: To be clear, he domain is $(0, \infty)$, and the codomain is $\{(x, \frac{1}{x}) : x \in (0, \infty)\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$, right?

Comment: @user793679 Correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \left\{\left(x, \frac{1}{x}\right) : x \in (0, \infty)\right\}$, the domain of $\vec{y}^{-1}$. Note that, for any point $(a, b) \in A$, i.e. where $b = \frac{1}{a}$, then $\vec{y}^{-1}$ maps $(a, b)$ to $a$. That is, $\vec{y}^{-1}$ is simply a restriction of the projection function $\pi_1(x, y) = x$. This projection function is continuous (indeed, non-expansive), hence so is its restriction $\vec{y}^{-1}$.